# Active border on certain page CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

So I'm in the making of doing a border button that is active when you are on that page. But when you press on the second border button, the first ones border removes and the second one is visible. It's basically the same thing as the ones on this site. The "Questions, Jobs, Documentation Beta, Tags" buttons. One lights up as you are on that page and the other turns off. I tried looking it up on google but couldn't find. And I tried looking at the code by "inspecting element" through Google Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the exact same HTML on each page. Then in each page, style the corresponding button differently by assigning an 'active' class only to that button. For example:

On the Home page

```
<a class="button active" href="index.html">Home</a>
<a class="button" href="about.html">About</a>
```

On the About page

```
<a class="button" href="index.html">Home</a>
<a class="button active" href="about.html">About</a>
```

CSS

```
.button {
background-color: grey;
}

.active {
background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Requires a little bit of CSS and HTML. If you want the result element to be "activatable" without changing the page, you'll need some JS, as well.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
button.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="active">Active Page</button>
<button>Not Active Page</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could think off is by adding an "active" Class to the button you want to light up on that page.